# How to use torrent magnetic link as video embedded link & use it for showing videos on a website?

Tags: php, html, torrent

I want to use `<video src="torrent link">` as `<video src="youtube link">`.
Is it possible?

I tried normally by making torrent links & directly showing on the page. But got errors.

[Here I can embed any link from any website & it works. So same thing I want to use on torrents to get video data & play on website. It will help us to make a website better](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vy5B.png)

[All videos are playing. Here you can upload from hard drive & from any website also.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iT5Xb.jpg)

Comment: I think you're going to have to explain a lot more what you want, what you've tried and which errors you got. Essentially provide us a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). As it is, it's hard to answer your question.

Comment: ok I will just give me some time

Comment: You'll need a torrent client that knows how to stream video, which most browsers don't have built in (if any).

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can simply use https://webtorrent.io

Working example:

```
var WebTorrent = require('webtorrent')

var client = new WebTorrent()

// Sintel, a free, Creative Commons movie
var torrentId = 'magnet:?xt=urn:btih:08ada5a7a6183aae1e09d831df6748d566095a10&dn=Sintel&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fexplodie.org%3A6969&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.coppersurfer.tk%3A6969&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.empire-js.us%3A1337&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.leechers-paradise.org%3A6969&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.opentrackr.org%3A1337&tr=wss%3A%2F%2Ftracker.btorrent.xyz&tr=wss%3A%2F%2Ftracker.fastcast.nz&tr=wss%3A%2F%2Ftracker.openwebtorrent.com&ws=https%3A%2F%2Fwebtorrent.io%2Ftorrents%2F&xs=https%3A%2F%2Fwebtorrent.io%2Ftorrents%2Fsintel.torrent'

client.add(torrentId, function (torrent) {
  // Torrents can contain many files. Let's use the .mp4 file
  var file = torrent.files.find(function (file) {
    return file.name.endsWith('.mp4')
  })

  // Display the file by adding it to the DOM.
  // Supports video, audio, image files, and more!
  file.appendTo('body')
})
```

Answer (score -1):

It is possible, but as far as I know, it can't be done using regular means (HTML/Javascript/PHP). The only way I know of is to use Java applet. Though it does work, it isn't really that efficient, depending on what you intend to do with it. Anyways, Bitlet got this working. They succeed in implementing the Bittorrent protocol in Java. You can check their code on [Github here.](https://github.com/bitletorg/bitlet)